Geometry Problem: Find the missing angle
So this came in an exam and I wasn't able to solve it, Here's the description:

In the picture, side $AB$ is equal in length to side $AC$, additionally, side $BD$ has the same length as side $BC$. $\angle ABD$ measures $\alpha$ and $\angle ACB$ mesures $60°- \alpha$. Find the measure of $\angle ADB$.
So Basically I tried angle chasing by using the fact that angles on a triangle add up to $180$ and also the fact that some of the triangles are isosceles so some of their angles are equal. This helped me find the measure in terms of $\alpha$ of most of the other angles, but I can't seem to find angle $x$. I also tried extending lines $BA$ and $CD$ and it turns out the meet at a $60°$ angle, but this didn't help much. Any help would be appreciated. Here's what the trivial angles are equal to:


Are you familiar with sine rule? If so, can you apply it in a way to calculate the ratio of the 2 sides which we're given are equal, in 2 different ways? Then solve that equation for $x$ (possibly in terms of $\alpha$).

@CalvinLin I did also try a sine rule approach. Basically I assumed two of the equal sides had length $1$ and computed the length of the other two equal sides in terms of sine of $\alpha$, eventually I found an expression that related the desired angle with the tangent of $\alpha$ but it was too complex for it to be useful, so I didn't even mention it.

Please add that your approach in.  $\quad$ I have an approach that just uses sine rule, and familiarity with the trigo identities. It's not nice though.

Construct a point $F$ (below $BC$) outside of the quadrilateral $ABCD$ such that $\triangle FBC \cong \triangle ABD$.
Notice that we have $|BF|=|BA|$ and $\angle ABF = 60^\circ$. Hence, $\triangle ABF$ is equilateral, i.e., $\boxed{|FA| = |FB|} = |AB|$.
For the triangle $\triangle BDF$, we notice that $(|BD|,|BF|,\angle DBF)=(|CB|,|CA|,\angle BCA)$, which implies $\triangle BDF \cong \triangle CBA$. Therefore, $|FD|=|AB|$, which we know equals $|FA|$ from above. In particular, $\boxed{|FD|=|FA|}$.
Now with this configuration, angle chasing is one way to conclude with. An alternative way is the following. We have established that $$|FA|=|FB|=|FD|,$$ which means that $F$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle ABD$. By angle-arc identities, this gives $$\angle ADB = \frac12 \angle AFB = \frac12 60^\circ = \boxed{30^\circ}. \ \blacksquare$$

Brilliant! i'm not sure I could have come up with that during the exam, especially the first step of constructing the point $F$, could you give me any insights on how did you come up with the idea of constructing point $F$?

Having two angles summing to $60^\circ$ is something quite specific. My motivation was to construct a $60^\circ$ angle at hand using these two angles.

Another way to force the $60^\circ$ angle, is to rotate $ADB$ counterclockwise by $ 60 ^ \circ + \alpha$ about $A$ to $AGC$, which also allows us to make use of the length condition. This makes $BCG$ an equilateral triangle (and hence the same $G$ in my solution).

Preamble: Here is a trigonometric brute force solution. This approach isn't motivating, esp compared to the other synthetic solutions.  I added it in as OP mentioned that they tried it, but didn't get a result. It turns out that they are pretty close to the result, so I'm showing them how to close the gap.
By sine rule, we get

$\triangle BAC: \frac{|BC|}{|AC|} = \frac { \sin ( 60 ^ \circ + 2 \alpha ) } { \sin ( 60 ^\circ - \alpha ) }$
$\triangle ABD: \frac{|BC|}{|AC|} =  \frac{|BD| }{ |BA|}  = \frac{ \sin (x + \alpha )  }{ \sin x }  = \cos \alpha + \sin \alpha \cot x$.

For simplicity, let $ \sin \alpha = s, \cos \alpha = c, \cot x = t$, so the second expression is just $ c + ts$ for some constant $t$. I'm presuming OP got to this step based on their comment.
To complete the solution, we need to simplify the first expression into a similar form. Observe that
$$ \frac{ \sin ( 60 ^ \circ + 2 \alpha ) }{ \sin ( 60 ^\circ - \alpha ) } = \frac{\sqrt{3} (c^2 - s^2) + 2cs } { \sqrt{3} c  - s } =   c + \sqrt{3} s$$
Thus $ \cot x = t = \sqrt{3}$ , so $ x = 30^\circ$.
Note: In a sense, we were lucky to have chosen $ \cos 2 \alpha = \cos^2 \alpha - \sin^2 \alpha$. This could have been motivated by considering coefficients, or we could have tested other expressions.

I was definitely not on the right track with this approach, since the expression I got for $\tan x$ was a lot  more complex. Regardless, thanks and also how can we know, once we have figured out that $\cot x = \sqrt{3}$, that $x = 30°$? I mean how can we discard other possible solutions such as $x = 210°$? Visually it looks like $30°$ should be the solution, but if we had to prove it, how could we? Actually Nevermind, I just remembered angles in a triangle add up to $180°$ while writing this, thanks for your response.

Here's a quick synthetic solution

Reflect $D$ across $BA$ to point $G$.
Observe that $|GB| = |BD| = |BC|$ and $\angle GBC = 60 ^ \circ$. Hence we have an equilateral triangle.
Observe that since $ABC$ and $GBC$ are both isosceles  triangles with base $BC$, hence $GA$ is the perpendicular bisector of $BC$.
Thus $ x = \angle BDA = \angle BGA = \frac{ 60^\circ}{2} = 30 ^\circ $.

